# A Magewell USB Capture HDMI alternative, just for screenshots?

Tags: usb, hdmi

I am the owner of a website that posts how-to guides on technology.

I am looking for an HDMI Capture USB Dongle, so I can take screenshots from other devices, such as the Raspberry Pi, or for screenshots outside of the OS from a 2nd PC (BIOS settings etc). I am not interested in recording video, just to get screenshots.

I have read about Magewell USB Capture HDMI, which has linux compatibility, and would probably work for my purposes. But it is too expensive (340 euros on Amazon.fr) and since I am not interested in capturing video, just static screenshots, it is probably an overkill.

Can you suggest a similar device that would work on Ubuntu at a lower cost? If it is available in amazon.fr, even better.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are very few video capture devices compatible with Ubuntu. It's mostly due to hardware manufacturers not wanting to open-source the device drivers. I too do tutorial video screen captures. The best solution I've found is to dual boot into Windows 7, and use a $150 Elgato HD60 USB 2.0 HDMI capture device.

I have found this device for $210 "IVC USB Driver Free HDMI Frame Grabber". There's also been reported success with the $200 Hauppauge HD PVR.

https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Hauppauge_HD-PVR

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ended up buying the Magewell, and it's awesome.